# How to add CSS code to the existing HTML code in github?

Tags: html, css, github

I recently created an account in github and I started coding with a simple exercise on aligning images using HTML and CSS code.

So I wrote the HTML code to align 4 images in a row and now I am stuck on styling part.

I'm unable to style it in `<style>` element of HTML. I.e. the changes are done within head using `<style>` tags are not having any effect, in simple there are no changes after I commit it.

I want to add CSS to the existing file. What are the ways to add? How to link CSS code?

Comment: Is your question about HTML stuff not working, or is it about Git not working, or both?

Comment: Where is your code in git?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen HTML stuff is working, but I am confused about CSS part, i.e how do I add CSS code ?

Comment: The answer by @zooted looks on the right track.  Maybe you should remove the GitHub tag

Comment: *Here*, in the SO, you can add HTML code by using the `<apostrophe>`. :-)

Comment: Your question is missing a [MCVE] so we can't see how you are trying to use `<style>`. The connection this has to GitHub is unclear. Are you trying to publish the result on GitHub Pages? Can you replicate the problem locally?

Comment: @Prathibha — That doesn't make anything clearer. Are you asking about editing the *bio* field on https://github.com/settings/profile ?

Comment: @Quentin ok sorry, I created my Github profile yesterday and started working on it by writing a simple code in HTML to align 4 images in a row. But now i want to add some CSS to it, which I am unable to add.

Comment: @Prathibha — You're repeating information you've already given without answering any of my questions. Where is this HTML? Is it an HTML document stored in a repository? Is it in the bio field of your profile? Is it somewhere else?

Comment: @Quentin yes it is in repository, no not the bio.

Comment: And how are you testing it? Are you loading it locally? Or are you trying to view it through the Github web UI?

Comment: @Quentin I am testing it on Github web UI. I wrote the html code in Read.md file.

Answer (score 2):

Store the CSS file in the same folder as the HTML file, then reference it in your HTML with a `link` tag.

`<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

> I wrote the html code in Read.md file.

GitHub allows you to write a README using [Markdown](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/). One of the features of Markdown is that it supports [embedding of HTML](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html).

As implemented by GitHub, however, it does not support stylesheets.

You can't use a custom stylesheet in your README.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot, I shall go through the  guide provided in github in detail. And sorry for being unclear about my question